# Cross orgin access denied in ionic framework and php

Tags: php, api, ionic-framework

I am working on a hybrid app for a website. I am using ionic framework 4 and my website code is written in PHP. My API code is written in PHP and uploaded on the server under the address http://www.example.com/projects/todaytv/api.

I consulted an expert and he told me that the API code is blocking cross platform access since I am working from localhost and the APIs are loaded on the server. What should I do to my API code in order to allow cross platform access?

This is the error message I get when I load content in ionic:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-orgin response http://www.example.com/projects/todaytv/api/getbasics with MIME type text/html. see http:www.chromesstatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

PS: I receive data and response in postman app.

Comment: Start by doing what the message already told you … _“see http://www.chromesstatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would normally be configured within your webserver config (Apache, etc). However, as you specifically request how to do with within the context of your API code, you can add the following output to your PHP boostrapper or index.php, etc

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Note, this must be added to your script before any output has been sent from the server.

Please also note that this solution is only suggested for a development environment and you should be more specific about the origins to which to provide access control on a production deployment.